# Adding a toolbar to a grid - Extjs

Tags: extjs, grid, panel, toolbar

I have the following grid here:

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.userlist',
    title: 'All Users',
    store: 'Users',

    initComponent: function () {
        this.columns = [{
            header: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            flex: 4
        }, {
            header: 'User ID',
            dataIndex: 'user_id',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            header: 'Address',
            dataIndex: 'address',
            flex: 3
        }, {
            header: 'Age',
            dataIndex: 'agee',
            flex: 5
        }];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Can a toolbar be added to the bottom of this grid or can they only be added to panels?

Also, how can I place normal text in a toolbar rather than a button?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes a grid panel inherits [`Ext.grid.Panel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel), you should be able to add:

```
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'top',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Left Button'
    }, {
        xtype: 'tbfill'
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Right Button'
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Hey thanks that worked great. And I'll check the documentation.

Comment: How could I place toolbar buttons on the left and right sides?

Comment: Add a { xtype: 'tbfill' } between the button configs in the toolbar

Comment: Very Nice! Thank you sir

Comment: While you're at it, how could I get the length of my grid size to display on this toolbar? (The length of the store/rows in the grid)

Comment: That last question is scope creep! I think it merits a new question.

Comment: In that case I would use a paging toolbar. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging

Answer (score 2):

Any component that has Docked layout can have toolbars docked.  Since `Ext.grid.Panel` extends `Ext.panel.Panel`, you can dock to it.  See the bbar config: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-bbar

You can add text items to your toolbar by adding this to the toolbar's `items`:

```
{ xtype: 'tbtext', text: 'My Text' }
```

Docs for this here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.TextItem

Answer (score 2):

Alternately you can also add button using '`bbar[...]`' which is equivalent to

```
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'bottom',
    items: [
        { xtype: 'button', text: 'Button 1' }
    ]
}]
```

this allows you to add buttons at the bottom of your gridpanel all other button properties are allowed to use.

sample code is here:

```
 bbar: [
      { xtype: 'button', text: 'Button 1' },
      { xtype: 'button', text: 'Button 2' }
    ]
```

for more details you can refer the doc: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-bbar